# sometime Elasticsearch throwing exception while saving logs to elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, express, elasticsearch

While saving logs in elasticsearch. some time logs save in ES but sometime its throwing exception

```
mapper_parsing_exception] object mapping for [meta.user_details.permissions] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value
```

I find a solution online that I need to delete index then reindex but I cannot do that.
any other solution.

Comment: If you can't make the field nullable, you would probably need to ensure `meta.user_details.permissions` is an object, never `null`, on the sending side.

Comment: somehow `permissions` is set as null, fix that

Comment: field is not null... thats  problem. but it saying its null